# Windows azure application developing step failed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, azure

This is my first time trying to develop a windows azure application on my visual studio 2010.
what I have done so far is:

- Open new project > C# > Cloud.
- Downloaded the SDK.
- Add new class with code that only displays my name and age.
- try to run this code locally and failed!

  [image]

My questions is:

- am I able to run the application locally? if yes the how?
- How can I deploy the application? (I already have an account)

Comment: did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes! Thanks A lot, I've added a web role and now I'm trying now to deploy it.

Comment: Ok, perfect, for any question you can ask around here!

Comment: It woks very well now! Thanks a lot Luis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for what I see your problem is not your windows azure sdk, the thing is that you are creating a WorkerRole project which is a Class Library type and that won't give you an output, for that you need to create a WebRole project.

here I let you this tutorial, it would show you how to create your first WebRole project.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=801

And this one would show you how to deploy on the cloud

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/125435/deploying-an-azure-application

Answer (score 1):

What type of application are you trying to build? Your error is because you are trying to run a class library, which isn't an executable.

There are primarily two types of applications that are hosted in Azure:

1. Website - These are just standard ASP.NET WebForms or MVC projects, hosted on Azure. These are the easiest to get going, and with the latest Azure release, require nothing special. Simply create a Web project, and git deploy to your [Azure Web Site](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/)
2. Worker Role - Worker roles are usually for background tasks like performing computations, sending emails, distributing work, etc. These can effectively be thought of as console applications that never end.

For example:

```
while(true)
{
    // do work here
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

When developing Azure applications, you need to either create a website (WebForms, MVC, WebAPI), a WCF service, or a console application to run as a background worker. Once you've built the application locally, then you can add an Azure Cloud project, which will handle the actual deployments.

Comment: This is incorrect information. Web Sites host .net, java, php, etc. They are indeed the easiest to get started, but certainly not limited to asp.net or mvc. The bigger issue is with Worker Role. Worker and Web Roles are part of Cloud Services, which provide further flexibility for apps (install MSIs, tweak registry, etc.). Web and Worker roles are nearly identical, aside from IIS being enabled vs disabled. Either may run a web app. Feel free to install tomcat/jetty/nginx, use IIS, run background processes in either one. They're both Windows Server VMs.

Comment: Of course, but given that he's asking about C# projects in Visual Studio, Java and PHP are rather irrelevant. It's also why I said "primarily", because while I have no data on it, I'd venture the number of MVC web roles vastly outnumber Tomcat installations on Azure.

Comment: My answer was perfectly suitable for his question, given his new status with working with Azure, his unsure about the type of project to create, and the tag's he used for his question. There's no reason to complicate things further for someone who wants nothing more than application to "display my name and age", and just needs a basic understanding on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run your application locally: Select the Azure application project in the Solution Explorer, right click, "Set as StartupUp Project" and run

To Publish: goto https://manage.windowsazure.com/ . Create a new web role and download the publishing settings.